# Splitting a single dynamic list in multiple lists using React?

Tags: reactjs

I am new around here. Doing my first own project with React, I am stuck to achieve this. After mapping a list using `.map()`, how can I have multiple lists split? I want them to be split by the first letter on each new `<ul>`, regardless the number of titles. Some titles have more than 5 or 10, for each letter. Some are not even showed, because there are no titles with that letter.

**My code**

```
<ul>
    {list.map((i) => (
        <li>
           {i.title}
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

**Result**

```
<ul>
  <li>title aa</li>
  <li>title ab</li>
  <li>title ac</li>
  <li>title ba</li>
  <li>title bb</li>
  <li>title bc</li>
  <li>title ca</li>
  <li>title cb</li>
  <li>title cc</li>
  …
</ul>
```

**Desired**

```
<ul>
  <li>title aa</li>
  <li>title ab</li>
  <li>title ac</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>title ba</li>
  <li>title bb</li>
  <li>title bc</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>title ca</li>
  <li>title cb</li>
  <li>title cc</li>
</ul>
  …
```

Thanks for any help and possible solution.

Comment: How would the items split?

Comment: I am receiving the data and it comes in alphabetic order. So I would like to split them by the first letter inside each new `<ul>`. Sorry I didn't make it clear in my question. I apologize for it. Thanks.

Comment: @Tamara you want to split it by 3 or on what condition do u want to split??.

Comment: Hi. I am sorry again. I'm gonna edit the question so I make it more clear. I want them to be split by the first letter, regardless the number on each of them. I am really sorry about it. I will fix the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reduce the `list` values following the desired pattern, then iterate over the sub-items one by one:

```
const grouped = list.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const key = obj.title.charAt(6);
  acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
  acc[key].push(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

which will lead grouped values as follows:

```
{
  a: [{
  title: "title aa"
}, {
  title: "title ab"
}],
  b: [{
  title: "title ba"
}, {
  title: "title bb"
}],
  c: [{
  title: "title ca"
}, {
  title: "title cb"
}]
}
```

You can then go through the `grouped` object and map to your proper layout:

```
Object.values(grouped).map(list => (
    <ul>
        {list.map((i) => (
            <li>
                {i.title}
            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it. I tried to implement this, but I am getting an error. Says: TypeError: obj.charAt is not a function. Any idea why is that?

Comment: You should update the `obj` with `obj.title`. I am updating the answer.

Comment: It indeed worked out. Thanks ever so much. I've been stuck on this for 2 days. I really appreciate your time for helping me. Have a nice one!

Comment: Glad to be in help :)

Answer (score 0):

It will depends on what is the condition to split your lists, but you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to generate a new list that will contains the splits that you need and then apply those splits to a new list.

```
function splitList(list) {
    return list.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        const lastSplit = acc[acc.length -1];
        if(lastSplit && lastSplit[0][0] === cur[0]) {
            return [...acc.slice(0, -1), [...lastSplit, cur]];
        } else {
            return [...acc, [cur]];
        }
    }, []);
}
```

After having your splits, you do the same thing you are doing for the li items, but for ul as well: (Replace the names of the variables)

```
{splitList(list).map(item) => (
    <ul>
        {item.map((i) => (
            <li>
            {i.title}
            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
)}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. I was able to implement that, but I still get all the items inside the single same `<ul>`. Would that be because of the `splitList` function? How can I change it to have it split by the first letter?

Comment: Take a look at this stackblitz with that code, you will see that it creates a new array with each new item. But I think the answer of tmarwen is better than mine, since it uses objects to store the values.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vpewnz?file=index.js

Comment: Indeed it is, as you mentioned. But when I `console.log` my I get the same result as it was first mapped. Nothing changed. I am giving a try with tmarwen's answer. Running into some issues. I hope I can find a way. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hope you can find a solution to your issue. If you want to any another try, just post here.

Comment: I was able to make it work with tmarwen's answer. I appreciate also you trying to help me. Thanks ever so much.